# File SharePoint title from table td?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint generated page. From there I am trying to extract the 2nd `<td>` value from the example below. How do I traverse the code and get that value using jQuery?

```
   <span id="part1">
       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="right" width="100%" nowrap="nowrap">
        <tbody>
           <tr>
    <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel"><h3 class="ms-standardheader"><a name="SPBookmark_Title"></a>Title</h3></td>
    <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
    <!-- FieldName="Title"
         FieldInternalName="Title"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
        Test Project
    </td>
</tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
    </span>
```

I tried:

```
    $('#part1 table tbody tr:nth-child(1)').each(function() {
    titleTxt = $(this).find(".ms-formbody").html();  
        alert(titleTxt);
});
```

But I am getting junk values.

### update

I used like this `$('#part1 > table:first tr:first td:nth-child(2)').html();` and getting results

```
<!-- FieldName="Title"
         FieldInternalName="Title"
         FieldType="SPFieldText"
      -->
        Test Project
```

how to igrone that comments

Comment: there is no `Title Project` in your sample. `Test Project`, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#part1 table tr:first td:nth-child(2)').html()
```

Or

```
$('#SPFieldText').html()
```

Comment: i used like this `$('#part1 > table:first tr:first td:nth-child(2)').html();` and getting results `<!-- FieldName="Title"
    FieldInternalName="Title"
    FieldType="SPFieldText"
    -->  Test Project.` how to igrone that comments

Comment: Move it outside of your td, ^_~  Or alternatively you'll have to do some sort of substring operation taking all the string after the index of '-->' +3.  If possible definately move the comment outside of your td, or better yet, don't leave comments in your productional code, :P